# Using bash what is the formal name of the > when sending output to a file

Tags: bash

In Ruby the >> is called the shovel operator. What is it called when in bash for example

```
cat "hello world" >> file.txt
```

how is it explained what this is doing using the proper nomenclature. I have heard it referred to as "piping" but the pipe is | so I am confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What is the formal name of the `>` when sending output to a file

It's a redirection operator.

Note:

- The pipe `|` symbol may also be informally called a redirection operator, but officially it is a control operator (see [What are the shell's control and redirection operators? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)).

> Both the input and output of a command can be redirected:
>
> ```
>  command  >  filename    Redirect command output (stdout) into a file
>
>  command  >  /dev/null   Discard stdout of command
>
>  command  2> filename    Redirect error output (stderr) to a file
>
>  command  2>&1 filename  Redirect stderr to stdout 
>
>  command  1>&2 filename  Redirect stdout to stderr
>
>  command  >> filename    Redirect command output and APPEND into a file
>
>  command  <  filename    Redirect a file into a command
>
>  commandA  < (commandB)  Redirect the output of commandB as file input to commandA
>
>  commandA | tee filename | commandB    Redirect commandA into filename AND commandB
>
>  commandA | commandB     Redirect stdout of commandA to commandB
>
>  commandA |& commandB    Redirect stdERR of commandA to commandB
> ```

Source [How-To: Redirection and Process Substitution - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-redirection.html)

Related:

- [Redirections (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)
- [What are the shell's control and redirection operators? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)